Where would I put the code for a data-target
I have the following line of code in an ASP.Net MVC app that I am trying to modify for a user at my company.
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddFacilityModal" data-backdrop="static">Add Facility</button>

I assume that AddFacilityModal would be the name of the form that the button is supposed to show and I tried to put the a .cshtml (Razor) page with the rest of the Razor pages but I got a 404 Cannot Find error.  Where in my app should I put the code for the form?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Donald

"I assume that AddFacilityModal would be the name of the form" - Specifically it's the unique id value of the element which represents the modal.  That element just needs to be on that page.  It's not really clear to me what prevents you from including it on that page.

Maybe I misworded the question.  I inherited an app from a developer who is no longer with the company and I don't have access to his latest code and I am trying to fix it.  How do I open a Razor page from an HTML button?

When you say "open a page" do you mean that you just want to navigate the user to another page?  As with a link?  Or something else?

I have a modal form that is in the form of a Razor page that I want to pop up from a button on the main form for the user to input some specific information.

Then are you looking to include a partial view in your main view?  That is, if the main view represents the "page" that to which the user has navigated, then this other partial view would be included as an element on that page.

Thank you for your help.  You pointed me in the right direction, I can display the form now, just have to figure out the code to make it work.
